# Метод startsWith в java. Почему не читает стринг?

Tags: java

Имеем два массива

`String[] roles = {"Городничий", "Аммос Федорович"}
String[] textLines = {"Городничий: Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор", "Аммос Федорович: Как ревизор?",`

Если я хочу проверить начинается ли в массиве `textLines` какая то строка со слова "Городничий", то могу применить метод

```
for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length - 1; i++) {
        if (textLines[i].startsWith("Городничий")) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
```

В вышеприведенном виде все фурычит.
Однако, не могу понять почему следующее не работает, ведь в аргумент подается такой же стринг:

```
String sRoles = roles [0];
System.out.println("sRoles = "+sRoles);//выводит sRoles = Городничий
```

Указываем sRoles в качестве аргумента:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length - 1; i++) {
        if (textLines[i].startsWith(sRoles)) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
```

Компилятор не ругается, но код уже не работает.Ведь в обоих случаях стринговое значение передается. Где мое непонимание этой ситуации, подскажите плиз.

Полный код

```
public class RolesTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] roles = {"Городничий\n", "Аммос Федорович\n"};

    String[] textLines = {"Городничий: Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор.\n",
            "Аммос Федорович: Как ревизор?\n"};

    String sRoles = roles [0];
    System.out.println("sRoles = "+sRoles);
    for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
        if (textLines[i].startsWith(sRoles)) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Можете выложить исполняемую программу со вторым вариантом, чтобы ошибку можно было [воспроизвести](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Я в java без году неделя ) то что вы щас попросили это значит выложить весь код?

Comment: Да не в Java дело :) В общем, да, только желательно перед этим убрать все не относящееся к делу и убедиться, что после этого ошибка еще есть

Comment: Выложил, все также ноль реакции

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] roles = {"Городничий\n", "Аммос Федорович\n"};
```

Строка `"Городничий\n"` не эквивалентна строке `"Городничий"` соответственно два приведенных примера не совпадают.

```
if (textLines[0].startsWith("Городничий")) {
    //сюда попадаем
}

if (textLines[0].startsWith("Городничий\n")) {
    //а сюда уже нет
}

if (textLines[0].startsWith(roles[0])) {
    //и сюда тоже нет.
}
```

В тексте подстрока «Городничий» есть, а подстроки «Городничий[перенос строки]» нет

Что делать с переносами строки зависит от ситуации. Можно их убрать вообще из строк поиска. Можно отфильтровывать перед поиском.

Comment: ну пааааллллин, полдня убил на поиск этой ошибки, вы правы все заработало, спасибо :) от души

Comment: @SergioBerluskony пожалуйста, удачи :)

Comment: @SergioBerluskony Зависит от того, что нужно отфильтровывать. Если лишний символ всегда один и всегда с конца, то можно отсекать его через [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), если переносы разные в разных местах то нужно либо пробегать по строке либо смотреть в сторону регулярных выражений.

Comment: ага, все понял, у меня как раз в списке значится обязательное использование упомянутых вами методов, вопросов больше не имею, еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 1):

У вас неверное условие в цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length - 1; i++) {
```

в данном случае длина 1, 1-1=0 и 0 < 0 будет false. Другими словами в тело цикла мы не попадаем ни разу. В приведённом выше рабочем кусочке кода просто длина больше, видимо это и ввело вас в заблуждение.

Достаточно будет исправить на это:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
    if (textLines[i].startsWith(sRoles)) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
}
```

Чтобы убедиться в правильности работы startsWith можете использовать этот пример:

```
for(String textLine: textLines){
    if (textLine.startsWith(sRoles)) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
}
```

Comment: нет ) не фурычит - ноль реакции

Comment: Добавил в ответ дополнение.

Comment: так я тоже пробовал ) не фурычит, консоль пустая